# Perl return code from Java Jar using System.exit

Tags: java, perl, jar, return-code

So I am using a perl script to call a command and then get the return code:

```
my $command = "java myjar.jar ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 2>&1";
my $result = open2( *Reader, *Writer, $command ) or die "Could not open 2-way pipe: $!\n";
my $result_return_code = $?;
```

This seemed to work fine.  However, for one of my tests it didn't seem to work.  I dove into the java code and this is what is printed.

```
try {
 ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Failed");
  System.exit(99);
}
```

Instead of getting an error code of 99 returned I receive a value of 0.  I have now tried dkatzel's edit and tried changing my code to the following:

```
my $command = "java myjar.jar ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 2>&1";
my $result = open2( *Reader, *Writer, $command ) or die "Could not open 2-way pipe: $!\n";
my $result_return_code = $? >> 8;
```

However I still get a return value of 0.  This change also changed one of my other test cases where I was getting a return value of 65280... and it now returns it as 255.

Ok.  Now I have attempted Zaid's edit and it works. Here is what my code looks like this (Also showing a little more code than I have before):

```
my $command = "java myjar.jar ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 2>&1";
my $result_pid = open2( *Reader, *Writer, $command ) or die "Could not open 2-way pipe: $!\n";

print Writer "stdinarg1=var1\n";
print Writer "stdinarg2=var2\n";
close(Writer);

my $result_string = <Reader>;
close(Reader);

waitpid($result_pid, 0);
my $result_return_code = $? >> 8;

my $result_return_code = $? >> 8;
```

Comment: Does it really matter? Anything that is non-zero is failure.

Comment: The issue is that it returns a return code of 0.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.  Fixed my original post to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the child process to return using [`waitpid`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html). This is because `waitpid` sets `$?`:

> The status is returned in `$?`

```
my $result = open2( *Reader, *Writer, $command )
               or die "Could not open 2-way pipe: $!\n";

do { ... }; # Interact with the process

waitpid( $result, 0 );

my $result_return_code = $? >> 8;
```

Answer (score 5):

In Java `System.exit(X)` will set the return code to X and exit the JVM immediately.  It doesn't matter if the call to exit is in the main method or anywhere else.

According to the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) `$?` is actually 2 values:  "The upper eight bits reflect specific error conditions encountered by the program (the program's exit() value). The lower eight bits reflect mode of failure"

So changing your code to this:

```
my $result_return_code = $? >> 8;
```

Will probably work.

---

**EDIT**

"This change also changed one of my other test cases where I was getting a return value of 65280... and it now returns it as 255"

Yes 255 is also -1 which is probably the real exit code from the JVM (look for `System.exit(-1)` somewhere in the java code.  The 65,000 exit code is because of the bit shifting `$?` does.  -1 sets all the bits which `$?` sets as the high 8 bits.

**Regarding the exit code of 0:**

Assuming the process has finished. Exit code 0 usually means success.  However the JVM is really bad with exit codes.  If the code doesn't explicitly call `System.exit()` then the JVM will return with an exit code of 0 *EVEN IF AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN*.  So it's possible if you are getting an exit code of 0 and it really should be an error, there might be a bug in the java code that is missing a call to System.exit();

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried changing it to this, however I am still getting a return code of 0.  It also changed another one of my test cases.  I edited my original post to show what happened.